# Java polymorphism: finding the right design pattern

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

**Disclaimer**: I know there are a lot of questions about polymorphism out there, but I couldn't find a suitable answer for my problem. If your Google-fu is better than mine, please forgive the dupe.

I have a model using inheritance, such as in the example below.

```
public abstract class Base {
// ...
}

public class ConcreteA extends Base {
    private String someString;
// ...
}

public class ConcreteB extends Base {
    private boolean someBool;
// ...
}
```

And I also have a `List<Base>`, which is composed of objects that are either `ConcreteA`s or `ConcreteB`s.

I need to generate a graphical view for each object in the list, but the resulting element is not the same for `ConcreteA`s and `ConcreteB`s. From the example above, the view for `ConcreteA` would be a text field, while the view for a `ConcreteB` would be a check box.

How can I achieve this using OO principles?

Comment: It's not quite clear what do you mean by "resulting element is not the same for `ConcreteA` and `ConcreteB`". But in general, OO principles state that Object should mostly be personally responsible for all actions with it, including rendering. So OO principles would dictate a `renderTo(Media)` method, but that is a WHOLE LOAD of cans of its own worms. So try to use something like a specialized renderer instances, each knowing how to render what.

Comment: Let me update the question to make this part clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you have is that you somewhere return a `List<Base>` when the caller must know the concrete type.

Usually this is caused because one tried to make a method more generic. E.g. if someone has this service methods

```
public List<ConcreteA> doSomethingA(){ ... }
public List<ConcreteB> doSomethingB(){ ... }
```

he might think it is a better idea to introduce a superclass, `Base` so that both methods can be substituted by

```
public List<Base> doSomething(){ ... }
```

This is a good idea if the caller is only interessted in a `Base` object. This means that `ConcreateA` and `ConcreteB` have some common behavior that the caller only depends on.

But in your case it seems that the caller needs the concrete type information that is not available anymore, because of the more generic method.

So you either must **preserve or reconstruct the type** information.

1. Preserve the type by using a custom return type instead of making the method generic

   ```
    public class Result {
        private List<ConcreteA> concreteA;
        private List<ConcreteB> concreteA;
    }

    public Result doSomething();
   ```
2. Recunstruct the type information using `instanceof`
3. Reconstruct the type information by introcucing a visitor pattern.

Comment: I like this answer. I was about to accept the one suggesting the Visitor pattern, because this is what I'm going to settle for, and the additional details you provide consolidate this choice. From a business point of view, it really is just a `List<Base>`, but each concrete class behaves differently, and I don't want to include everything in the business model. Thank you for taking the time to write this up. :)

Answer (score 2):

Not a pattern - this is what abstraction is all about. Declare a method you want all subclasses of `Base` to implement and each must implement it in their own way.

Obviously you would pass parameters and/or get results of the methods.

```
public abstract class Base {
    abstract void graphicalView();
}

public class ConcreteA extends Base {
    @Override
    void graphicalView() {

    }
}

public class ConcreteB extends Base {
    @Override
    void graphicalView() {

    }
}

public void test() throws IOException {
    List<Base> bases = new ArrayList<>();
    for ( Base b : bases ) {
        b.graphicalView();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some way to export this functionality out of the model classes while keeping this behavior? I feel like handling the graphical interface has nothing to do in the models.

Comment: @RichouHunter Then make the `graphicalView` return an object that can be rendered. Maybe make it return some XML you can then run through an XSLT transform into HTML. Or maybe return a `State` which can then be rendered externally.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for **[Visitor Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)**.

From Wikipedia :

> In object-oriented programming and software engineering, the visitor
>   design pattern is a way of separating an algorithm from an object
>   structure on which it operates. A practical result of this separation
>   is the ability to add new operations to extant object structures
>   without modifying the structures. It is one way to follow the
>   open/closed principle.
>
> In essence, the visitor allows adding new virtual functions to a
>   family of classes, without modifying the classes. Instead, a visitor
>   class is created that implements all of the appropriate
>   specializations of the virtual function. The visitor takes the
>   instance reference as input, and implements the goal through double
>   dispatch.

Comment: Not certain this is `Visitor` - feels more like [Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern#Java) to me.

Comment: I see your point. But in this case, I think it would be better if you could separate the structure and the model (`List<Base>` of `ConcreteA` and `ConcreteB`) from the behavior (Drawing). Which is not the case with Bridge design pattern.

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers. The Visitor pattern looks like the way to go (thanks for suggesting it), but René's answer provides very useful information.

Answer (score -1):

In such cases, I usually use generics something like this

```
public abstract  class Base <T extends  Shape>{
public abstract T drawShape();
```

}

```
public class ConcreatA extends Base<Circle> {
@Override
public Circle drawShape() {
    return null;
}
```

}

```
public class ConcreatB extends Base<Square> {
@Override
public Square drawShape() {
    return null;
}
```

}

So now you can use list of Shapes